# how to include numpy with cythonize-script?

Tags: python, numpy, windows-10, anaconda, cython

Recently I start looking into Cython, and the Anaconda distribution have this handy script `cythonize` which allow to do

```
 >cythonize -i foo.pyx
```

to compile files in place.

My question is how I can use that script to include numpy so my `cimport numpy` work properly??

I have try with

```
>cythonize -X include_path=C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include  -i foo.pyx
>cythonize -s include_path=C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include  -i foo.pyx
```

also with `include_dir=...`, `include_dirs=...` both with -X and -s

if I use -X I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\cythonize-script.py", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(Cython.Build.Cythonize.main())
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Cythonize.py", line 185, in main
    options, paths = parse_args(args)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Cythonize.py", line 172, in parse_args
    options, args = parser.parse_args(args)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\optparse.py", line 1387, in parse_args
    stop = self._process_args(largs, rargs, values)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\optparse.py", line 1431, in _process_args
    self._process_short_opts(rargs, values)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\optparse.py", line 1536, in _process_short_opts
    option.process(opt, value, values, self)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\optparse.py", line 785, in process
    self.action, self.dest, opt, value, values, parser)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\optparse.py", line 805, in take_action
    self.callback(self, opt, value, parser, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Cythonize.py", line 38, in parse_directives
    value, relaxed_bool=True, current_settings=old_directives)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Options.py", line 424, in parse_directive_list
    raise ValueError('Unknown option: "%s"' % name)
ValueError: Unknown option: "include_path"
```

with -s I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\cythonize-script.py", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(Cython.Build.Cythonize.main())
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Cythonize.py", line 196, in main
    cython_compile(path, options)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Cythonize.py", line 90, in cython_compile
    **options.options)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 809, in cythonize
    ctx = c_options.create_context()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py", line 581, in create_context
    self.cplus, self.language_level, options=self)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py", line 90, in __init__
    self.include_directories = include_directories + [standard_include_path]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'bool' and 'list'
```

---

Yes, I can make a setup.py, but I find that very annoying and it leave that build folder there, while cythonize don't do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like it's not possible to pass in the include dirs via the command line version of `cythonize`.

The problem is that looking in the cython source code, it expects options to be boolean:

https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Build/Cythonize.py#L48

So when you include a path, it gets converted to `True`:

```
cythonize -i -s include_path=path_to_numpy_include test.pyx
```

and the options are parsed as:

```
{'directives': {}, 'options': {'include_path': True}, 'python3_mode': None, 'annotate': None, 'excludes': [], 'build': True, 'build_inplace': True, 'parallel': 12, 'force': None, 'quiet': None, 'lenient': None, 'keep_going': None}
```

which results in the type error you're reporting:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'bool' and 'list'
```

I think your best bet is to just use a proper `setup.py`.

Comment: well, I guess I would make a automatic setup generator to spare me for writhing such a simple setup file each time for each cython example...

Comment: If you're just prototyping stuff, I often just work in a jupyter notebook and use the `%%cython` magic.

Comment: that sound good, but I'm not used to work with it, I'm more used to work with console

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by setting environment variables interpreted by your C compiler (which cythonize runs as a subprocess). For example, with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html) or [clang](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/clang.html#environment):

```
C_INCLUDE_PATH=$(python -c 'import numpy; print(numpy.get_include())') cythonize -i foo.pyx
```

Comment: This works for me. @Copperfield consider selecting this answer.